# Why am I receiving a 500 status when trying to connect with ASANA api?

Tags: oauth, localhost, asana, asana-connect

I am using this example: https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class/blob/master/examples/oauth.php to learn how to use the asana's oauth. I already registered my app on the asana's developers webpage. But, when I get the asana's response with my `'redirect_url'?code=0%XXXXXXX`, localhost gives me a 500 status. I don't know why, does anyone know how I can solve it?

I tried using the other examples in there: https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class/blob/master/examples/, but I wasn't able to make them run either, I always get a 500 status. I think that the problem must be in my server, but I don't how solve it. Maybe changing something on the `.htaccess` file, but I don't really know what to put in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to use the Asana API from PHP may I recommend the official first-party client: https://github.com/Asana/php-asana

It also contains examples of how to use with OAuth and is officially supported by us at Asana :-)